# I have a list of same value on dart lang. How can I get each of their Index?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I am having an issue while I am making app with flutter. The problem is:

I have a list look like

```
[null, null, null, null]
```

or

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

the values are same. issue is I need a list of widget depending on the list. I need to get each of the items index from the list to make my widget.

But when I call indexAt method it always return 0. How can I get actual position from this? Please help me with your suggestion.

Comment: You should add something to the values to differentiate them

Comment: Yes I can add values but then I need some extra states to reach my goal. Is there any thing like JS .map where I can get both value and index?

Comment: `list.asMap()` should work

Comment: You want to get each item one by one from the list, why not just loop through the list? A simple loop would be enough to get you the index needed

Comment: A couple of different ways is described here: https://fireship.io/snippets/dart-how-to-get-the-index-on-array-loop-map.